# Void Linux upower issues

Tags: power-management, battery, void-linux, lxqt

I recently installed voidlinux in a Samsung NC10 netbook. I installed LxQT but after starting LxQT cannot find the battery. Looking at the problem it seems that `upower` cannot start correctly. If I run `/usr/libexec/upowerd` I get these messages:

```
(upowerd:4419): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:07:48.902: g_dbus_proxy_get_connection: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed

(upowerd:4419): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:07:48.903: g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(upowerd:4419): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:07:48.903: g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed

(upowerd:4419): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: 10:07:48.903: Could not acquire inhibitor lock: Unknown reason

(upowerd:4419): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:07:48.905: g_dbus_proxy_get_connection: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed

(upowerd:4419): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:07:48.905: g_dbus_connection_signal_unsubscribe: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
```

And if I try to run `upower` I get:

```
(upower:8422): UPower-WARNING **: 10:14:12.323: Cannot connect to upowerd: No se pudo conectar: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

which is odd since `upowerd` is present in the system. I already tried to reinstall these packages and still get the same problem. The system is up to date and I'm using kernel `5.15.17_1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add `dbus` to the services: `ln -s /etc/sv/dbus /var/service/`